# I'm not able to inflate Fragment from FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating one `FragmentActivity` and inside its `onCreate` function I am setting a layout using `setContentView` which contains one `Fragment`, but I am getting the following error

both the `Fragment` and `FragmentActivity` are from  `android.support.v4.app`
activity_main.xml is a layout

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

          android:id="@+id/contact_list"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:name="com.ss.contact.ContactsListFragment"/>
```

I have checked many threads but everythings seems fine

```
1) Class name in `android:name`
2) my activity is derived from `FragmentActivity` 
3) i have set my activity as a `Launcher` activity
4) have called `super.onCreate`  and right after `setContentView` in `FragmentActivity`
```

but still I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ss.home/com.ss.contact.ContactsListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
    at com.ss.contact.ContactsListActivity.onCreate(ContactsListActivity.java:51)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060006
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1061)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getBoolean(Resources.java:843)
    at com.ss.contact.ContactsListFragment.onCreate(ContactsListFragment.java:151)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
```

here is  `onCreateView` of `Fragment`

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the list fragment layout
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_fragment, container, false);
    }
```

Comment: Please show onCreateView implementation of your `Fragment`

Comment: is your ContactsListFragment is in com.ss.contact package or anywhere else?

Comment: show us your fragment layout xml.

Comment: why are you calling super.onCreate after setContentView??

Comment: you try get boolean value on `ContactsListFragment` please post `ContactsListFragment` and show `line 151` to us

Answer (score 0):

Please don't call  `super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);` in your fragment.

Comment: What is the package name where your Fragment is?

Comment: its inside `com.ss.contact`  and app name is `com.ss.home`

Comment: Try   `android:class`instead of  `android:name` in xml layout

Comment: sorry `class` without `android:`

Comment: Ok... your fragment is only Element in xml file. Please wrap this fragment in `LinearLayout` or something like that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46627/discussion-between-jedil-and-hunt)